# Split and save text string on scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I need split a substring from a string, exactly this source text:

> Article published on: Tutorial

I want delete "Article published on:" And leave only

> Tutorial

, so i can save this 
i try with:

```
category = items[1]
category.split('Article published on:','')
```

and with

```
for p in articles:
            bodytext = p.xpath('.//text()').extract()
            joined_text = ''
            # loop in categories
            for each_text in text:
                stripped_text = each_text.strip()
                if stripped_text:
                    # all the categories together
                    joined_text += ' ' + stripped_text
            joined_text = joined_text.split('Article published on:','')
    items.append(joined_text)
            if not is_phrase:
                title = items[0]
                category = items[1]
                print('title = ', title)
                print('category = ', category)
```

and this don't works, what im missing?

error with this code:

> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: And what specifically is going wrong?

Comment: I don't think I understand you correctly, but are you looking for `category.split(':')[1]`?

Comment: i cant modify the text, if i do a print, i got the text
" Article published on: Tutorial" without any modifications ( i want remove "article published on"

Comment: Can you post the code including the print statement?

Comment: I'm still confused. What is the input HTML you are scraping, and what is `articles` in this context? What is the content of `items`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can't really reason about your code without knowing what state it's in as it enters the code you've provided.

Comment: You need to assign the result of `joined_text.split()` to something.

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just forgot to assign the result:

`category = category.replace('Article published on:', '')`

Also it seems that you meant to use `replace` instead of [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). The latter also works though:

`category = category.split(':')[1]`

Comment: thanks !
the problem was what i have a + with unicode at the beginning of the sentence invisible on the html of the source (painted with the same colour of the theme)